# Why the ' ', hexadecimal value 0x0C, is an invalid character. Line 1, position 1. throws in WPF

Tags: wpf, xamlparseexception

When i load a xxxx.XAML into WPF frame it throws the error `' ', hexadecimal value 0x0C, is an invalid character. Line 1, position 1.` how to find which is causing the problem. when the xxxx.XAML is in another project's start page, it works fine, when i load that condent of xxxx.XAML in arother project  means it throws an error why this is happening ?

And also i upgrade my project from vs 2010 to vs 2012

Comment: The problem is caused by a file that starts with a form feed. It shouldn't be hard to identify that.

Comment: For me, what fixed this issue was setting the "Build Action" in the properties of the XAML file from "Page" to "Resource"

Comment: What fixed it for me was the extra carriage returns and line feeds at the end of my .xaml file. They are invisible, hard to notice, but when I removed them, this error went away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my file name, i have upper case X. while reading load the file i use small x. so it cause the problem

Answer (score 13):

In my case it was that I wanted to load a XAML file using the code below, but it's Build Action was set to Page instead of Resource:

```
Uri uri = new Uri(resourcePath, System.UriKind.Relative);
Stream stream = Application.GetResourceStream(uri).Stream;
UIElement view = (UIElement)XamlReader.Load(stream);
stream.Close();
```

Comment: Need not only to change Page to Resource, but also Custom Tool from MSBuild:Compile to nothing

Comment: Thanks, thanks a lot! I've been struggling with this simple task for a couple of hours now, I was starting o get infuriated, but I'm happy now :)